# Wrong ImportError when trying to import a broken package twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed a strange behavior while trying to import a broken package twice. Let's consider the following package:

```
| package
|--| __init__.py
|--| module1.py
```

with `module1.py` empty and `__init__.py` containing:

```
from package import module1
from package import module2
```

On the first try to import `package`, an `ImportError` is raised because `module2` is missing:

```
>>> import package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/package/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from package import module2
ImportError: cannot import name 'module2'
```

But on the second try, the `ImportError` complains about `module1`:

```
>>> import package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/package/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package import module1
ImportError: cannot import name 'module1'
```

even though `module1` has been successfully imported before. It is even available in `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules["package.module1"]
<module 'package.module1' from '/tmp/package/module1.py'>
```

However, this seems to be fixed in Python 3.5, maybe because [circular imports involving relative imports are now supported](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.5.html#other-language-changes).

What is going on exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The first time around, `package.module1` is imported and from then on exists in `sys.modules`. However, due to the import error on `package.module2`, the import of `package` itself doesn't succeed and so, `package` does not end up in `sys.modules`.

The second attempt to import `package` will handle the import of `package.module1` differently as it already exists in `sys.modules`. The code path this time around assumes at some point that if a module with a dotted name exists in `sys.modules`, all parents do as well. This assumption is, however, not fulfilled after the failed import of `package` at the first attempt.

In short, importing a package, which may cause more packages and modules to be imported, is not atomic with respect to filling `sys.modules`, while Python up to 3.4 made some assumptions that would require atomicity.